# How does keras calculate accuracy for multi label classification?

Tags: neural-network, text-mining, keras, lstm

I am using this code for a multilabel problem classification.

```
from __future__ import print_function

from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.models import Model
from keras.datasets import imdb

max_features = len(vocabDic)
maxlen = 500  # cut texts after this number of words (among top max_features most common words)
batch_size = 32

train_set = sequence.pad_sequences(train_set, maxlen=maxlen)
test_set = sequence.pad_sequences(test_set, maxlen=maxlen)

print('train_set shape:', train_set.shape)
print('test_set shape:', test_set.shape)

print('Build model...')
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 128))
model.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(90, activation='sigmoid'))

# try using different optimizers and different optimizer configs
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Train...')
model.fit(train_set, train_labels,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=15,
          validation_data=(test_set, test_labels))
score, acc = model.evaluate(test_set, test_labels,
                            batch_size=batch_size)
print('Test score:', score)
print('Test accuracy:', acc)
```

My problem is there are 90 classes and the accuracy is too high from the second epoch. I suspect keras is computing something incorrectly.
Any clues?

Edit: I calculated the total recall of the model. It is barely 5%( 5 times better than random). Is it a normal behavior for such a problem?

Comment: It may happen and is not strange. depending on your data you may have even better results in first epoch. I've seen the similar thing in mnist

Comment: I see you're using binary cross-entropy for your cost function. For multi-class classification you could look into categorical cross-entropy and categorical accuracy for your loss and metric, and troubleshoot with sklearn.metrics.classification_report on your test set

Comment: Just to clarify: are you talking about *multi-label* (individual samples may belong to more than one classes) or *multi-class* (individual samples belong to one and only one class) classification here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59931955/9214357).

Your problem is that Accuracy is not the right metric for multi-label tasks. Try something different like AUC, precision, recall, accuracy@k, precision@recall.
The choice of binary_crossentropy is correct since you are predicting each label independently.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using binary_crossentropy?  You should be using categorical_crossentropy.  However, if you insist on using binary_crossentropy change your metric to metrics=['binary_accuracy', 'categorical_accuracy'] (this will display both accuracies).

Comment: Using binary_crossentropy is in fact correct. If the problem is a multi-label classification problem, it turns into K binary classification problems. Using softmax would be wrong, as doing that would result in raising the probability on one class lowering others.

Comment: This comment by @OliverNi is correct.

Comment: The answer has 3 upvotes and at the same time, a comment which is pointing a mistake @Tophat should update the answer or clarify the comment. Especially this point "Why are you using binary_crossentropy? You should be using categorical_crossentropy"