# Which Keras metric for multiclass classification

Tags: python, keras, multiclass-classification, metric

I have a **multiclass classification** data where the **target** has **11 classes**. I am trying to build a Neural Net using **Keras**. I am using `softmax` as activation function and `categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function. I have one hot encoded the target before passing it into the net. The issue I am facing is **which Keras metric should I use for this purpose?** The [official documentation](https://keras.io/api/metrics/) does not mention which metric is suitable for multiclass classification.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59305514/tensorflow-how-to-use-tf-keras-metrics-in-multiclass-classification) link mentions to use `categorical_accuracy` as the metric for multiclass classification but other than that, all other question on this site are about multilabel classification metrics like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53874485/multi-label-classification-keras-metrics/59931955#59931955) and [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/25752/how-does-keras-calculate-accuracy-for-multi-label-classification) link.

Is there any implementation of lets say `f1_score` in Keras using the custom metric function, since `f1_score` is the go to metric for multiclass classification I guess?

**EDIT 1:**

Would something like this work using the custom metric functionality in Keras?

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

def my_metric_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    f1 = f1_score(y_true, y_pred)
    return f1

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(input_dim = 12, units = 128, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(units = 32, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(units = 11,  activation = 'softmax', kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = [my_metric_fn])
history = model.fit(train_x5, train_encoded, validation_split = 0.2, epochs = 5, batch_size = 1000)
```

**EDIT 2:** This is giving me an error in the last line as follows:
 `OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a tf.Tensor as a Python bool is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.`

Comment: For multiclass classification you can simply use a categorical cross entropy loss function. Depending on whether or not the values are one-hot encoded you would have to use either the sparse categorical cross entropy loss or the normal categorical cross entropy loss.

Comment: I am asking about the metric to use not the loss.

Comment: It would help if you said what you would like the metric to evaluate and why it should be different from the loss function.

Comment: The metric needs to be any metric that is used in multiclass classification like `f1_score` or `kappa`. But Keras has not yet implemented them yet unlike sklearn.

Comment: `it should be different from the loss function.` I find this statement interesting as it implies that it is not necessary to use metrics to evaluate the model. Does this mean we can just use the loss function for the evaluation and not the metrics?

Comment: Yes, please look at the Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/api/metrics) "Metric functions are similar to loss functions, except that the results from evaluating a metric are not used when training the model. Note that you may use any loss function as a metric."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to implement F1 score in Keras:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

def f1(y_true, y_pred):    
    def recall_m(y_true, y_pred):
        TP = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
        Positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
        
        recall = TP / (Positives+K.epsilon())    
        return recall 
    
    
    def precision_m(y_true, y_pred):
        TP = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
        Pred_Positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    
        precision = TP / (Pred_Positives+K.epsilon())
        return precision 
    
    precision, recall = precision_m(y_true, y_pred), recall_m(y_true, y_pred)
    
    return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))
```

Comment: I would need to call the function in the `model.compile` where I would need `y_pred` which I can only get after I fit and evaluate the model. But fitting and evaluating comes after compiling so how can I call the function in `model.compile`? Even if I pass the function as a list (as I have done in EDIT 1), I will still get the same error as in EDIT 2!

Comment: Ok I implemented it in my model and its works! NVM my previous comment!XD

Comment: You could also use the built in method here https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/F1Score